# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client ODP.NET

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g, adodb, odp.net, oracleclient

I landed in a tricky situation. I am working on a legacy .NET application that used ADODB (only 32bit dlls available) in conjunction with Oracle.DataAccess (32/64 bit available) which was running earlier on 2003 server with some version of Oracle (I am not sure on the version number).

Now with minimal changes I need to port this to work on 2012 server (64bit) and Oracle 11g with .NET 4.0. When I use the 64bit of Oracle client, the system is failing at ADODB. When I am using 32bit Oracle client, it says `The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client.`

The environment / tools used are:
Oracle 11g, ODP.NET, ADODB, Windows 2012 (64bit), .NET 4.0

Is there a way to solve this riddle?

**Edit :**

I tried with System.Data.OracleClient instead of ODP.NET I got the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

Comment: You have a version mismatch. Can you use the Oracle installer to install the exact same ODP.NET version on the target server? You can try searching the target machine for all copies of Oracle.DataAccess.Client to make sure there aren't old versions floating around.

Comment: That should read Oracle.DataAccess.dll